# Flashlight app doesn't install on all phones and Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK

Tags: android, eclipse, android-camera, android-manifest

Ive written an android app for basic flashlight .I've tested the app on 5 devices galaxy s2, note 3, moto g ,micromax canvas hd , xolo q800.

The app runs fine on s2,note 3 and canvas hd .Whereas in the remaining devices when I try to install the signed apk which is signed using debug key store,in the the middle of the installation process the package manager gets crashed but the app icon is created and when I click on it , it shows a toast message "app isn't installed"

Ive found some similar threads but referring to them i couldn't resolve my issue.

Here is the  manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.flashone"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18
    " />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
                                                                                                                                                                        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"                                                                    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_APPWIDGET">
    <activity
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
       android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:name="com.example.flashone.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>

 </manifest>
```

EDIT:Now there is one more issue occuring 
     didn't change anything in the manifest and this started out of nowhere
     and my testing device right now is galaxy s2 which is 4.1.2 API 16

```
[2014-07-28 21:59:12 - FlashOne] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK
[2014-07-28 21:59:12 - FlashOne] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2014-07-28 21:59:12 - FlashOne] Launch canceled!
```

The logcat shows following messages

```
    07-28 22:35:08.058: D/AndroidRuntime(539): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START       com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
    07-28 22:35:08.058: D/AndroidRuntime(539): CheckJNI is ON
    07-28 22:35:08.877: D/AndroidRuntime(539): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
    07-28 22:35:08.937: W/ActivityManager(91): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/FlashOne.apk
    07-28 22:35:08.999: W/ActivityManager(91): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/FlashOne.apk
    07-28 22:35:09.007: W/PackageParser(91): /data/app/vmdl156967055.tmp (at Binary XML file line #6): Requires development platform 18          but this is a release platform.
    07-28 22:35:09.147: D/dalvikvm(91): GC_EXPLICIT freed 32K, 14% free 14620K/16903K, paused 24ms+9ms
    07-28 22:35:09.217: D/AndroidRuntime(539): Shutting down VM
    07-28 22:35:09.237: D/dalvikvm(539): GC_CONCURRENT freed 123K, 78% free 466K/2048K, paused 0ms+1ms
    07-28 22:35:09.237: D/dalvikvm(539): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
    07-28 22:35:09.257: I/AndroidRuntime(539): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `android.hardware.camera` and `android.hardware.camera.autofocus` are silently declared from `CAMERA permission`, as said [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html) (last section).

I think you're installing from apk and not the Play Store because you wouldn't be able to see the application if the device hasn't got both of these features. I think that when installing from unkown sources the package manager doesn't handle the missing feature well.

You will need to declare both features with the "required" set to false (I think `camera` is actually required, `autofocus` is not).

Answer (score 0):

Ok the part of the question is solved

Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK

the mistake was here

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="7"
android:targetSdkVersion="18
" />
```

which should be written as

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="7"
android:targetSdkVersion="18" 
 />
```

just the placement of the double quote mattered.